# run genfromdata get an OSError

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

When I tried this code in local sublime editor

```
data = np.genfromtxt('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaustubholpadkar/Linear_Regression-Gradient_Descent-Octave/master/data.csv', delimiter=',')
```

I got an error like this

```
OSError: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaustubholpadkar/Linear_Regression-Gradient_Descent-Octave/master/data.csv not found.
```

While I ran it in virtual environment, it worked and downloaded the data into the same folder with the py file.

What should I do if I want it works in local, not only in virtual environment?